# Regular Expression: Replace a word conditionally

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to find a regular expression that can match character and replace them but conditionally. While i am somewhat successful in finding the character but while replacing i am finding some issues.

for eg:
If i have a string saying "mnh ghty stuf"

so i m replacing each char with `a=1 b=2 c=3  till y=25`

so its output will be "`123 4567 891011`"

**but if i find words having first char staring from letter K the words should not be replaced**

i.e for ex= `abc kdefg hijk its output must be like this 123 kdefg 891011`

can any 1 please tell me how to do this ?

I tried the below code but it didnt work though.

```
if(count>0) 
{ 
    str = ""; 
    String str123=enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase(); 
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("t(\\w+)(\\s)").matcher(enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCas‌​e()); 
    while(matcher.find()) 
    { 
        str1=matcher.group(1); 
        System.out.println("k letter "+str1); 
    } 
    str=enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase(). replace("a","1"). replace("b","2"). replace("c","3"). replace("d","4"). replace("e","5"). 
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You would be better off not using regex and looping your string char by char.

Comment: @anubhava : Yep i started with that only, but there too i faced problems with some specific words, so tried this one replacing that solution..am working on this...It helps me to some extent but not completely.:(

Comment: While looping you can always detect a space and then check whether next char is `k` or not. If it is `k` then ignore whole word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

common:

```
final String        input  = "abc kdefg hijk";
final StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder( 1024 );
```

1st method:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\w+)" );
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );
while( matcher.find()) {
   final String word = matcher.group( 1 );
   output.append( ' ' );
   if( word.charAt( 0 ) == 'k' ) {
      output.append( word );
   }
   else {
      for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i ) {
         output.append( 1 + word.charAt( i ) - 'a' );
      }
   }
}
```

2nd method:

```
final String[] words = input.split( "\\W+" ) ;
for( final String word : words ) {
   output.append( ' ' );
   if( word.charAt( 0 ) == 'k' ) {
      output.append( word );
   }
   else {
      for( int i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i ) {
         output.append( 1 + word.charAt( i ) - 'a' );
      }
   }
}
```

common:

```
System.out.println( output.toString());
```

same output in both case:

```
123 kdefg 891011
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

`(?:\b([^k ]+\w+\b)|(\b[k]\w+\b))`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zE8eX4/4)

It captures in two different groups, first one to be replaced, second one to be keep.

Option 2:

`\b([^k ]+\w+\b)`

It captures only work not starting by k, on the loop over the matches you do your conversion and replace original match by your converted string.

I'm not enought comfortable in Java to give a demo code, just regex for me :)

If its of no use, tell and I'll delete.

Comment: what about this `kbc kbc lmn`? Not working [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zE8eX4/2)

Comment: ?? It works as OP asked, not taking in account the words starting with k. But I see what you mean, it does not output the whole string with the words not escaped. I did let that to OP, But I'll enhance it.

Answer (score 0):

My Java is rusty but I would use this regex:

```
String str123=enter_text.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\bk\w*|([a-z])").matcher(str123);
```

Then if group 1 doesn't exist you skip that or replace it with the entire match (effectively does nothing). If group 1 exists you replace it with:

```
Integer.toString(Character.codePointAt(matcher.group(1), 0) - 96);
```

The codePointAt gives you the ASCII-value of the letter. a = 97, so minus 96 gives you 1, etc.